# What is better practice? Pass class member by pointer or identifier?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class, and I want another class or function to read on its members. (For example, UI reading a player's scores and other things.)

Let's say I have this happening a lot, with many different variables, over a long period of time.

Do I, A, pass it by a pointer to the other class so it can read from memory...

```
class VariableReader {
public:
    int* read;
    void GiveYourVariableToMe(int* var) {
        read = var; // keep accessing the variable with this "read" member
    };
};
```

or Do I, B, create an array of objects and an object identifier for it to use

```
std::map<std::string, int> VariablesToRead;

class VariableReader {
public:
    std::string identity;
    void GiveYourVariableToMe(std::string Identifier) {
        VariablesToRead[identity]; // keep accessing this variable with the through the map
    };
};
```

Or is there something else I should do?

EDIT: Maybe I didn't explain it well enough.

I'm talking about if I had a class with a bunch of member variables and I want the variable that it reads from to be object specific, like:

```
class Player {
public:
    int var1;
    int var2;
    int var3;
    int var4;
    int var5;
    int var6;
    int var7;
};
```

and I create, let's say a bunch of text objects that when updated, display the variable assigned to them

```
void Game() {
    TextObject obj1; // displays var1 when updated
    TextObject obj2; // displays var2 when updated
    TextObject obj3; // displays var3 when updated
    TextObject obj4; // displays var4 when updated
    TextObject obj5; // displays var5 when updated
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with just polling the parameter from the object? Do you have some performance problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Both seems wrong but it is not clear what you are trying to do. What is the problem with having regular member variables in the class that need them?

Comment: Getting pointers or refs to data in foreign classes is bad practice as it allows to manipulate the data without the control of the containing class. A bit better is having Getters/Setters, but this also destroys information hiding as all the data struct is now hard related to the UI. So having a serializer which is able to serialize to all and everything, including a UI seems ok to me. Maybe you may look for  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller. But yes, if you only want to hack some data to a UI, all of them is overkill ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you want to avoid either of these. If another class, such as some class X, needs to read the value of some thing owned or known to class B, usually you provide some member function of B that provides the value, with a name such as `GetFoo`. For example, some function XF in X will have an object `b` of type `B`. Maybe it was passed by reference, or the function in X constructed it, whatever. To get the value of `Foo` from `b`, XF will use `b.GetFoo()`. The `GetFoo` function will look like:

```
class B
{
private:
    Some declaration of Foo;
…
public:
    TypeOfFoo GetFoo() { return Foo; }
};
```

This is preferable to providing XF some pointer to the `Foo` in `b` because it means class B is free to change how it manages `Foo`. `Foo` could be a dynamically allocated object whose address changes at times, or it could be a value that is computed rather than stored directly. And, once you let X have a pointer to `Foo`, then the implementation of B cannot change so that `Foo` is a different type or is otherwise managed differently unless all the code in X and other uses of `Foo` changes. Generally, you want to avoid any classes outside B having much information about what is inside B. They should not know the types or locations of B’s internal data.

Supposing you have decided that class X **must** have some way of accessing `Foo`, then letting it have a pointer to a `const` `Foo` is likely better than the `map` and `string` version you propose. That causes run-time lookups of names, which is just wasteful if the names are known at compile time. Even so, with a `const` pointer to `Foo` being made available, you need to carefully document the obligations and behaviors of the classes. Once a `b` object has allowed some other class to have a pointer to `Foo`, `b` cannot let the address of `Foo` change, and `b` must not be destroyed unless the holders of pointers to its `Foo` are done using it. These sorts of interlocking relationships are prone to errors and should be avoided.

Stick with giving X a `GetFoo()` function in B until you have **very** good reason to do something different. If you need to select from multiple values to be obtained, then `GetFoo(identifier)` is okay, where `identifier` is an integer or `enum`, and `GetFoo` looks up the object in an array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question but I think what you want to do is to pass an instance of one class to another class

```
class Player
{
public:

  // your "variables"
  int32_t Score() {.. }
};

class UI
{
public:
  void ShowScores(const Player& player)
  {
    std::cout << player.Score(); 
  }

};
```